# How to load file only in single post page through function.php?

Tags: uploads

I want to include a file only in single post page. I've following code but not working;

```
if (is_single()){
require_once(dirname(__FILE__) . '/inc/lazy-load.php');
}
```

I mean i just want to load lazy-load in only single post page. but above code is not working. Any idea? Hope to get a solve for this problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[is_single](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/is_single/) function checks for $wp_query global variable is loading single post of any post type or not , $wp_query is set after running query_posts function that loaded after [wp](https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/wp) action hook.

So you should call this function in the right order ( hook )

```
add_action( 'wp', 'include_single_lazy_load' );

function include_single_lazy_load() {
    if( is_single() ) {
        require_once(dirname(__FILE__) . '/inc/lazy-load.php');
    }
}
```

Comment: great it works, but I am getting little bit different problems, actually I want to exclude this lazy load in single post of a specific category. I have jquery image slider in single post of Gallery category, the lazy load is blocking to load all images there or unnecessarily fixing the height of images too, So I just want to exclude the lazy load only on that gallery's post. Any Idea?

Comment: if you want to exclude specific post , you can pass the post ID , slug or title to the function like that: **is_single( 'post-slug' )** , and if you want to exclude generic posts that have gallery , you can get post ID like that : global **$post; $post->ID** , and load the file lazy load script if this post has gallery like that : **if( get_post_meta( $post->ID, 'gallery', true )**. @KaBin

Answer (score 0):

The best way would be to create a child theme then duplicate your `single.php` template file and edit that directly.

> **[CHILD THEMES](https://codex.wordpress.org/Child_Themes)**
>
> A child theme is a theme that inherits the functionality and styling
> of another theme, called the parent theme. Child themes are the
> recommended way of modifying an existing theme.